# unable to access custom component property from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have created one custom component, alternative of Select component, on click shows ul and on click hide ul.

when I click I can set value to the state inside function, but i want to access the value in parent component.

so my component is

```
 const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
    const [value, setValue] = useState();
    return (
        <>
            <button
                className='btn'
                onClick={() =>
                    showMenu ? setShowMenu(false) : setShowMenu(true)
                }>
                {props.name}
            </button>
            <ul className={showMenu ? "" : "hide"}>
                {props.listsa.map((element) => {
                    return (
                        <li
                            key={element.key}
                            value={element.value}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                setValue(e.target.value);
                            }}>
                            {element.label}
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        </>
```

I want to access value mentioned above functional component in parent component, which is my app.js

as shown below, this is return method of parent component.

```
<div className='App'>
            {/* <Main /> */}

            <OptionsComponent name='ABC Menu' listsa={abc} />
             {/* here I want to use that value to perfom operations/ also on change it should show changed value */}
        </div>
```

I tried using localStorage.setItem("value":value) it works but that will use browser memory so I am looking for alternative way.

I tried exporting variable, it shows undefined, also I tried making varibale global, it works but doesnt reflect change.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to bring the state up and pass it down, instead:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState();

return (
    <div className='App'>
        {/* <Main /> */}
        <OptionsComponent name='ABC Menu' listsa={abc} value={value} setValue={setValue}/>
    </div>
```

And

```
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
        <button
            className='btn'
            onClick={() =>
                showMenu ? setShowMenu(false) : setShowMenu(true)
            }>
            {props.name}
        </button>
        <ul className={showMenu ? "" : "hide"}>
            {props.listsa.map((element) => {
                return (
                    <li
                        key={element.key}
                        value={element.value}
                        onClick={(e) => {
                            props.setValue(e.target.value);
                        }}>
                        {element.label}
                    </li>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
      </>
    );
```